# Всплывает ошибка ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу вот такой код, довольно простой, я начинающий. Мне надо выводить числа определенного условия из массива.
Использовать надо функцию, функцию задать через input, использовать генератор.

```
def t(s):
    x = [i for i in s if i % 3 == 0]
    print(x)

r = int(input("Введите список"))
print(t(r))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def t(s):
    x = [i for i in s if i % 3 == 0]
    print(x)


r = map(int, input("Введите список: ").split())
Введите список: 1 2 3 6 7 8 9

print(t(r))
[3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, все получилось